# Null/blank processes on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, malware

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Mate. Recently I am observing blank processes in System Monitor as shown in the image. Usually, there is only one but sometimes there are a lot as in the image below. I am concerned whether this might be some kind of virus or something similar.

I am not sure whether this will be helpful or not. I have a bash script (self written) to show battery percentage when battery is **full** or **half**. This script uses inbuilt `sleep` command.
[image: Blank/Null processes.]

Answer (score 1):

I think what happens is due to the way the System Monitor handles the tasks.
My guess is that it gets the list of processes, and then updates them for a while.
If a process does not exist anymore, it shows like no process name, no Memory in use, etc...
To know if the process exist you can do:

```
ps auhx | grep 123
```

Where 123 is your process number.

You can also:

```
cat /proc/123/cmdline
```

That will return the command that was used to execute that process.

For example:

```
cat /proc/1414/cmdline 
dbus-run-session--gnome-session--autostart/usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
```

If the folder /proc/PID/ does not exist, the process finished execution and is not present on the system anymore.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I found that the processes were created by an infinite loop in a bash script I made to monitor the battery percentage. When I stopped the script, those processes stopped spawning.